# Calculate frequency of word pattern in documents

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I am trying to calculate frequency of word pattern in documents.
e.g. How many times word pattern "Natural Language Processing" is appearing in the documents.
I tried it using TF-IDF and Bag of words. however, it is giving me frequency of each word separately.

Is there any way to solve this problem using NLP, Text mining?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn` has a sutiable function that does pure word occurrence counts, called [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).
The documentation page also lists a parameter called `ngram_range`, which allows you to specify the minimum/maximum length of your word patterns that you would like to consider.

Keep in mind that TF-IDF applies some additional normalization on top of the frequencies, so it does not result in the same values obviously.